# Why is Rsquared smaller in whole sample than k-fold cross-validated?

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, caret

I want to get a cross-validation $R^2$ for a linear regression model with one predictor to get a measure of how well my model predicts rather than explains data (in R with package caret). I assumed that my $R^2$ measure computed with the whole data set would be overestimated because it is (over)fitted to the observed data.

```
# the data
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(pred = rnorm(163))
data$crit <- data$pred / 2 + rnorm(163)
#plot(data$pred, data$crit)

# regression on whole sample
summary(lm(crit ~ pred, data))
```

I thought that cross-validation would overcome this problem and yield a more appropriate estimation (= smaller $R^2$). This is true for the leave-one-out cross-validation method (LOOCV):

```
# LOOCV
library(caret)
train.control <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV")
model <- train(crit ~ pred, data = data, method = "lm",
               trControl = train.control)
model
```

But for a k-fold cross-validation $R^2$ is larger than for the whole sample:

```
# 5-fold with 10 repititions
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 5, repeats = 10)
model <- train(crit ~ pred, data = data, method = "lm",
               trControl = train.control)
model
```

**My main question**: Why is $R^2$ greater for the 5-fold cross-validation than for the whole sample?

**Further questions**:

- In my original data the differences between $R^2$ derived from the different methods showed the same pattern, but they were much more pronounced (0.019 for the whole sample, 0.001 for LOOCV, 0.047 for 5-fold CV). Can I trust these measures if they differ so strongly?
- I want to calculate the residual standard error from the cross-validation results. Is there a simple option to get this result? Or is this calculation correct? I multiply the criterion variance of the whole sample with the df to get the total sum of squares, multiply with $1-R^2$ to get the residual sum of squares, divide by the df of the residual standard error and finally take the square root:

```
sqrt((1-model$results$Rsquared) * var(data$crit) * 162/161)
```

Comment: Those CV approaches will differ, especially LOOCV. in LOOCV you train on n-1 samples and test on 1 sample at a time, this is much different story then training on many samples and testing on many samples as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was surprised that the methods would result in so divergent estimates. However, my main point is that I don't get why the model with the **whole** dataset does not give the highest $R^2$. Can you help me with this question? I thought that this model is fit exactly to the observed data and would thus be overfitted, which I am aiming to avoid with CV.